# copy and rename files in a directory in a specific pattern

Tags: python

I would like to copy a file lying in a directory equal to the number of times the other files lying in that directory  and then rename all the new files.

For example, there are 3 files in a directory, filename1.xls, filename2.xls and filename3.xls. I would like to copy Filename1.xls 2 times (as there are 2 files in the directory excluding filename1.xls )and then rename each copied file as filename2.xls and fiilename3.xls. Hope my question is clear. Thanks, AD

Comment: You want to take one file and overwrite all other files in the directory with a copy of that first file?

Answer (score 0):

hm... just get the amount of files in directory, copy your file N times and save them as

```
for number in range(amount):
    "feliname%r.xls" % number
```

if I understand what you mean

Comment: filenames = os.listdir("C:/")
for i in range(len(filenames)):
    if filenames[i].startswith("F"):
This is the piece of code I've started with.
I would like to create multiple copies of 'master.xls' file which is also lying in the same directory.The number of copies will be equal to the number of files in that directory starting with letter 'F'.Then I would like to rename all the newly created copies of 'master.xls' with filenames starting with "F". Say, three filenames start with "F", I would like to make 3 copies of 'master.xls' and then rename with the original name starting with "F".

Comment: @user2001139: don't put relevant info in the comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14480589/edit) instead.

Comment: so make a list of files starting with F and save your copies with this names.

Answer (score 0):

To replace content of all files that have names that start with `"F"` and that are adjacent to a file given at the command-line with its copy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1] # provide file you want to multiply
dirname, basename = os.path.split(filename)
for name in os.listdir(dirname):
    path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
    #note: os.path.normcase() might be required to compare names
    if name.startswith("F") and name != basename and os.path.isfile(path): 
       shutil.copy2(filename, path) #note: some metadata is not copied
```

Note: if the copy fails; the destination file might be destroyed. You can copy to a temporary file first in this case before replacing the destination.